# How to print this string in python

Tags: python

String to print:
He said "I'm Sorry"

i did this

```
1)"He said"
2)"He said Sorry"
3)"He said \"\""  >> He said ""
4)"He said \"Im Sorry\"" >> He said "Im Sorry"
5)"He said \"I'm Sorry\"" >> He said "I\'m Sorry"    why???
```

Comment: Try this :  `print "He said \"I'm Sorry\""`

Comment: your #5 works for me. What version of python are you using? I'm doing `print("He said \"I'm Sorry\"")`

Comment: Thanks guys. wasnt using print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using the REPL loop<sup>1</sup> (read-evaluate-print loop) to print it out, which reverts to using single quotes and suitable escaping:

```
>>> "He said \"I'm Sorry\""
'He said "I\'m Sorry"'
```

If you use `print` directly (which you'll have to use in a program since REPL won't be there to echo the results automagically), you can use either of:

```
>>> print("He said \"I'm Sorry\"")
He said "I'm Sorry"

>>> print('He said "I\'m Sorry"')
He said "I'm Sorry"
```

Obviously, I prefer the latter since it's fewer keystrokes :-)

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know that's redundant but it's a well established idiom what with PIN number and ATM machine and so on :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be:

```
>>> print("""He said "I'm Sorry" """)
He said "I'm Sorry"
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote.

Comment: ups, thank you @Andy for noticing that, I added the missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are getting all messed up.

You the easy solution is:

```
print "He said \"I'm Sorry\""
```

What we do here is we start the `string` with double quotes.
Then we want to start the quotation; but the double quotes were already used to start off the string, so we must use an `escape sequence`, which will allow us to use double quotes, without disrupting the quotation order.
Then we can use a regular single quote in the word `I'm`. We again use an `escape sequence` to end the quote.
After that, we use a regular double quote to end the string.

To make it more readable:

```
print "  He said   \" I'm Sorry \"    "
```